# Which chainguard (or alternative chainring) for a Shimano FC-M 510 crankset

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, chainring

My commuter bike is equipped with a Shimano FC-M 510 crankset,
the teeth configuration being 44/36/22. Unfortunately, the largest
chainring has no chainguard attached to it (and also no holes), so that
occasionally my clothes gets stained with the chain lube.

As far as I can see, one can still buy original Shimano chainrings for this model
that do have holes for attaching a chainguard, e.g. here

https://www.bike-components.de/en/Shimano/FC-M540-9-speed-Chainring-for-Chain-Guards-p14246/

(it's for M540, but is listed as compatible to M510). According to the [manual](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-FC-M510-L-1873A.pdf), the original Shimano part no. for the chainguard itself is `Y-1C618000`, yet I couldn't find even a single online store in Germany that still sells those chainguards.

So my question is, are there other chainguards that are compatible to `Y-1FM98100`?

Perhaps I could just buy a chainring with a chainguard from a different Shimano crankset model, that would still work with the remaining parts of my M510? I understand that it might not work 100% perfectly, but usually I don't switch gears so often and the bike is for commuting only (within a city), so it wouldn't be a major disaster. The current drive train consists of Deore XT FD-M738, Deore XT RD-M761, CS-HG51 and CN-HG71c. I'm familiar with adjusting front and real derailleurs (did it myself multiple times) and have all the necessary tools. I just don't know how far different parts of Shimano cranksets are compatible or incompatible with each other.

Comment: Perhaps a better strategy would be to look for chain guards that mount to the chainring bolts?

Comment: Would it be unsafe to drill a few small holes in the chainring?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I've tried that already with a Hebie item, but it was extemely wobbly and removing it from the chainring bolts was a huge pain afterwards. So I'd rather go with a Shimano solution.

Comment: @MaplePanda Probably not, but which chainguard should I then take? Are they somehow standardized?

Comment: @vsht If you have the chainguard on hand, you would just lay it over the outer chainring, mark out the corresponding holes, and drill. Looking at the M510 crankset, you could probably just zip tie it on too. A couple tiny holes probably wouldn’t hurt too much, especially since you’re commuting and not busting out 1200 watt sprints or anything.

Comment: Splattering clothes with lube points towards overdoing the lubing. If it's just from  occasional contact between chain and trouser-leg good old ankle-clips are a valuable solution. (And the keep the cold from creeping up!)

Comment: @Carel Actually I already use ankle-clips, but I agree that there was too much lube, so I wiped off some of it from the chain. Anyway, the problem is now solved: one obviously shouldn't put too much emphasis on Shimano's official compatibility lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for all the tips. I ended up buying a new FC-M540 chainring with holes (since my current one was already quite old) and a chainguard that is actually meant for FC-T671/FC-T781 (Y-1MP98070). Needless to say that the chainguard fits perfectly to the FC-M540 chainring, although officially they are listed as incompatible.

Everything works perfectly, I didn't even have to adjust the front derailleur.